# How to push both key and value into an Array in Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, key-value

I am reading **RSS feed** and pushing both Title and Link into an Array in **Jquery**.

What i did is

```
var arr = [];

            $.getJSON("displayjson.php",function(data){
                $.each(data.news, function(i,news){
                    var title = news.title;
                    var link = news.link;
                    arr.push({title : link});
                });                      
            });
```

And i am reading that array again using

```
$('#show').click(function(){
                $.each(arr, function(index, value){
                    alert( index +' : '+value);
                });
            });
```

But it Giving me **Output** as

```
1:[Object Object]
2:[Object Object]
3:[Object Object]
```

like this ...

How i can get both **tile** and **link** as a pair ( **title as key and link as value**)

Answer (score 223, accepted):

There are no keys in JavaScript arrays. Use objects for that purpose.

```
var obj = {};

$.getJSON("displayjson.php",function (data) {
    $.each(data.news, function (i, news) {
        obj[news.title] = news.link;
    });                      
});

// later:
$.each(obj, function (index, value) {
    alert( index + ' : ' + value );
});
```

In JavaScript, objects fulfill the role of associative arrays. Be aware that objects do not have a defined "sort order" when iterating them (see below).

**However**, In your case it is not really clear to me why you transfer data from the original object (`data.news`) at all. Why do you not simply pass a reference to *that* object around?

---

You can combine objects and arrays to achieve predictable iteration *and* key/value behavior:

```
var arr = [];

$.getJSON("displayjson.php",function (data) {
    $.each(data.news, function (i, news) {
        arr.push({
            title: news.title, 
            link:  news.link
        });
    });                      
});

// later:
$.each(arr, function (index, value) {
    alert( value.title + ' : ' + value.link );
});
```

Answer (score 59):

This code

```
var title = news.title;
var link = news.link;
arr.push({title : link});
```

is not doing what you think it does. What gets pushed is a new object with a single member named "title" and with `link` as the value ... the actual `title` value is not used.
To save an object with two fields you have to do something like

```
arr.push({title:title, link:link});
```

or with recent Javascript advances you can use the shortcut

```
arr.push({title, link}); // Note: comma "," and not colon ":"
```

If instead you want the key of the object to be the content of the variable `title` you can use

```
arr.push({[title]: link}); // Note that title has been wrapped in brackets
```

Comment: thanks @6502 - arr.push({[title]: link}); was useful

Answer (score 25):

I think you need to define an object and then push in array

```
var obj = {};
obj[name] = val;
ary.push(obj);
```

Answer (score 23):

```
arr[title] = link;
```

You're not *pushing* into the array, you're setting the element with the key `title` to the value `link`. As such your array should be an object.

Answer (score 4):

You might mean this:

```
var unEnumeratedArray = [];
var wtfObject = {
                 key    : 'val', 
                 0      : (undefined = 'Look, I\'m defined'),
                 'new'  : 'keyword', 
                 '{!}'  : 'use bracket syntax',
                 '        ': '8 spaces'
                };

for(var key in wtfObject){
    unEnumeratedArray[key] = wtfObject[key];
}
console.log('HAS KEYS PER VALUE NOW:', unEnumeratedArray, unEnumeratedArray[0], 
             unEnumeratedArray.key, unEnumeratedArray['new'], 
             unEnumeratedArray['{!}'], unEnumeratedArray['        ']);
```

You can set an enumerable for an Object like: `({})[0] = 'txt';` and you can set a key for an Array like: `([])['myKey'] = 'myVal';`

Hope this helps :)