# Push parent arrays element and chidren array into new array in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

```
"items": {
"hotdrinks": [
  {
    "id": "9aa113b4-1e4e-4cde-bf9d-8358fc78ea4f",
    "price": 20,
    "name": "Tea",
    "img": "../assets/img/HotDrinks/1_udupibhavan.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "9aa113b4-1e4e-4cde-bf9d-8358fc78ea4f",
    "price": 25,
    "name": "Coffee",
    "img": "../assets/img/Hot Drinks/2_udupibhavan.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "9aa113b4-1e4e-4cde-bf9d-8358fc78ea4f",
    "price": 50,
    "name": "Hot Milk",
    "img": "../assets/img/Hot Drinks/3_udupibhavan.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "9aa113b4-1e4e-4cde-bf9d-8358fc78ea4f",
    "price": 70,
    "name": "Horlicks",
    "img": "../assets/img/Hot Drinks/4_udupibhavan.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "9aa113b4-1e4e-4cde-bf9d-8358fc78ea4f",
    "price": 80,
    "name": "Badam Milk",
    "img": "../assets/img/Hot Drinks/5_udupibhavan.jpg"
  }
],
```

}

json i want to achieve using javascript. im just new to handling arrays and objects. thanks**found the answer given by Jeeva which works perfectly**
future answers are welcome since we can know diffferent methods to achieve the same json object

```
 dataArray = [
 {title:"Hotdrinks",
 content: [{
        "id": "9aa113b4-1e4e-4cde-bf9d-8358fc78ea4f",
        "price": 20,
        "name": "Tea",
        "img": "../assets/img/HotDrinks/1_udupibhavan.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": "9aa113b4-1e4e-4cde-bf9d-8358fc78ea4f",
        "price": 80,
        "name": "Badam Milk",
        "img": "../assets/img/Hot Drinks/5_udupibhavan.jpg"
      }
]}
```

Comment: which language you are using?

Comment: Can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825899/how-to-push-both-key-and-value-into-an-array-in-jquery

Comment: @Shravan Jain javascript.!

Comment: okay. I guess you got the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this. This can be achieved by iterating the object.

```js
const data = {
              "items":{
                "hotdrinks":[
                  {
                  "id":"9aa113b4-1e4e-4cde-bf9d-8358fc78ea4f",
                  "price":20,
                  "name":"Tea",
                  "img":"../assets/img/HotDrinks/1_udupibhavan.jpg"
                  },
                  {
                  "id":"9aa113b4-1e4e-4cde-bf9d-8358fc78ea4f",
                  "price":25,
                  "name":"Coffee",
                  "img":"../assets/img/Hot Drinks/2_udupibhavan.jpg"
                  },
                  {
                  "id":"9aa113b4-1e4e-4cde-bf9d-8358fc78ea4f",
                  "price":50,
                  "name":"Hot Milk",
                  "img":"../assets/img/Hot Drinks/3_udupibhavan.jpg"
                  },
                  {
                  "id":"9aa113b4-1e4e-4cde-bf9d-8358fc78ea4f",
                  "price":70,
                  "name":"Horlicks",
                  "img":"../assets/img/Hot Drinks/4_udupibhavan.jpg"
                  },
                  {
                  "id":"9aa113b4-1e4e-4cde-bf9d-8358fc78ea4f",
                  "price":80,
                  "name":"Badam Milk",
                  "img":"../assets/img/Hot Drinks/5_udupibhavan.jpg"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
            

var dataArray = []

for(k in data.items){
  var dataObj = {}
  dataObj.title = k
  dataObj.content = data.items[k]  //You can also access the object values by using bracket ([]) notation
  dataArray.push(dataObj)
  
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(dataArray))
```

Answer (score 0):

The above expected output json is not valid. We can achieve the following.

```
[{"title":"Hotdrinks"}, {"content": [  
     {  
        "id":"9aa113b4-1e4e-4cde-bf9d-8358fc78ea4f",
        "price":20,
        "name":"Tea",
        "img":"../assets/img/HotDrinks/1_udupibhavan.jpg"
     },
     {  
        "id":"9aa113b4-1e4e-4cde-bf9d-8358fc78ea4f",
        "price":25,
        "name":"Coffee",
        "img":"../assets/img/Hot Drinks/2_udupibhavan.jpg"
     },
     {  
        "id":"9aa113b4-1e4e-4cde-bf9d-8358fc78ea4f",
        "price":50,
        "name":"Hot Milk",
        "img":"../assets/img/Hot Drinks/3_udupibhavan.jpg"
     },
     {  
        "id":"9aa113b4-1e4e-4cde-bf9d-8358fc78ea4f",
        "price":70,
        "name":"Horlicks",
        "img":"../assets/img/Hot Drinks/4_udupibhavan.jpg"
     },
     {  
        "id":"9aa113b4-1e4e-4cde-bf9d-8358fc78ea4f",
        "price":80,
        "name":"Badam Milk",
        "img":"../assets/img/Hot Drinks/5_udupibhavan.jpg"
     }
  ]}]
```

If you are okay with this then i'll give you the sample code for the same.